# Write meta_query for group fields in Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I think the ACF docs are pretty sparse on how to query sub fields of a group made with Advanced Custom Fields.

Example:

```
acf_custom_dates_group
acf_custom_date_group_child
```

How would I perform a meta_query for values in the child field?

Answer (score 4):

The trick here was to **combine group and subfield key names**. I believe t he LIKE operator is also necessary.

```php
/*
The name of my custom group: acf_custom_dates_group
The name of my sub field: acf_custom_date_group_child

Name combined as 'key' and separated by underscore (see below)
*/

$format_value = ''; // set by ajax
$myquery = new WP_Query([
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'posts',
    'meta_query' => [
        //'relation' => 'OR',
        //'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key' => 'acf_custom_dates_group_acf_custom_date_group_child',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => $format_value
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: King of the internet! This was taking me hours to figure out why I wasn’t getting any results for my meta_query. Every example out there assumes your field is at the top level of your field group and not in a sub group. Shame this isn’t better documented, thanks for your post. Cheers!